# How are Postgres database files updated?

Tags: postgresql

I'm curious how the `/base` files are updated for a Postgres database. Do the segments correspond to segments of each table, so that only a few segment files are updated after an update to subset of the table? Or will the update to the table cause changes to all or a majority of the segment files?

Basically, I'm interested in the reliability of these updates to the `/base` files for backup purposes. Given the usage of WAL for PITR, I have a feeling that the files are not updated in any coherent way for my purposes.

According to [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/storage-file-layout.html):

> When a table or index exceeds 1 GB, it is divided into gigabyte-sized
>   *segments*. The first segment's file name is the same as the filenode;
>   subsequent segments are named filenode.1, filenode.2, etc. This
>   arrangement avoids problems on platforms that have file size
>   limitations. (Actually, 1 GB is just the default segment size. The
>   segment size can be adjusted using the configuration option
>   `--with-segsize` when building PostgreSQL.) In principle, free space map and visibility map forks could require multiple segments as well,
>   though this is unlikely to happen in practice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was cross-posted also to DBA. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/220150/how-are-postgres-database-files-updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the link you quote, you will also find that tables and indexes are organized in 8KB blocks, and a table row is always contained in one block.

So modifying a row will affect at most two blocks: the one that contains the old row version, and one where the new version is written. So no more than two table files can be affected.

Indexes are less predictable: if the update is HOT, nothing will be modified. If an index page split becomes necessary, several blocks may be affected.

Since your main concern seems to be reliability: modifications to the data files are asynchronous to the SQL statements that cause them. The information is logged in WAL and then written to shared memory. The modifications will hit the disk during the next checkpoint at latest.

The WAL is responsible for the durability of all transactions since the last checkpoint.